# Is there any way for a constructor to require certain values egg. non-negative ints

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to ensure I don't ever accidentally pass a negative value to my class is there any way to require the `cycleCount` variable to be positive the way I require it to be an `int` or do I just have to implement checks within the code using it?

```
class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int cycleCount;
  final int workTime;
  final int breakTime;
  const TimerPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.cycleCount,
      required this.workTime,
      required this.breakTime});

  @override
  State<TimerPage> createState() => _TimerPageState();
}
```

Comment: This is what constructor preconditions, exceptions, _and documentation_ is for. Also take a look at Predicate Types (aka Dependent Types and Refinment Types).

Comment: There is no way to check arguments' values at compile-time.  You will need runtime checks (ideally an `assert` in the constructor's initializer list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `assert` after setting your constructor with the condition that should be true to make it work without any exception, and the message if the condition is false

```
  class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int cycleCount;
  final int workTime;
  final int breakTime;
  const TimerPage(
      {Key? key,
      required this.cycleCount,
      required this.workTime,
      required this.breakTime}) : assert(cycleCount > 0, "you can't pass a negative integer to cycleCount");

  @override
  State<TimerPage> createState() => _TimerPageState();
}
```